# Удалить из текста в ячейке символы между первой парой скобок

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Ячейка **Масло моторное (АРТ3541232) синтетическое (5л)**

Подскажите функцию чтоб удалить все что находится между первыми скобками, в итоге на выходе получить

**Масло моторное синтетическое (5л)**

Comment: Длина названия артикула всегда одинакова?

Answer (score 0):

При одинаковой длине названия артикула:

```
=ЗАМЕНИТЬ(A2;ПОИСК("(";A2);13;)
```

Для произвольной длины:

```
=ЛЕВБ(A2;ПОИСК("(";A2)-1)&ПСТР(A2;ПОИСК(")";A2)+1;99)
```